# Is there a way to show a specific XML's preview rather than activity_main when building on the device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-studio-2.3

I did some research on this topic but could not find my answer.

I am making a news app using RecyclerView and CardView.

I created a layout XML file named "list_row" that includes the CardView. I want to see the preview shown for this XML on my phone when I build it.

---

Expected
[image]

---

`activity_main` currently only has a progress bar but when I build, this is the XML that gets loaded.

Actual
[image]

---

Any help on this would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the layout in the java code.

1. Open your MainActivity class. It can be found in
   'java>(packagename)>MainActivity.java'
2. Open it and look for `R.layout.activity_main` in the `onEnable` method.
3. Change that to an other layout, such as `R.layout.list_row`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in your `RecyclerView`:

```
   tools:listitem="@layout/list_row"
```

It will show many layouts in your `Preview` mode

Answer (score 0):

Just change the layout id passed on setContentView() inside onCreate() method of MainActivity.